# How to sync client and backend while are in different repositories and having different pipelines

Tags: github, continuous-integration, repository, microservices, continuous-deployment

That's not an actual problem that I have but I would like to know what are the different approach that people are taking in order to solve a very common scenario.

You have one or many microservices, and each of those have schemas and an interface that clients are using to consume resources.

We have a website in a different repo that is consuming data from one of those microservices, let's say REST API.

Something like

Microservice (API): I change the interface meaning that the JSON response is different.
Frontend: I make changes in the frontend to adapt the response from the microservice.

If we deploy the Microservice before deploying the frontend you will brake the frontend site.

So you need to make sure that some have deployed the new version and then deploy the microservice.

This is the manual approach but hos is the people tracking that in an automated way like not be able to make a deployment without having the correct version of the frontend deployed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the safest one is trying to be always backward compatible by using versioning on service level that means having different version of the same service when you need to introduce a backward incompatible change.
Lets assume you have a microservice which serves products in a rest endpoint like this

> /api/v1/products

when you do your backward incompatible change you should introduce the new version by keeping the existing one still working

> /api/v1/products
> /api/v2/products

You should set a sunset for your first service endpoint and communicate this with your clients. In your case it is the frontend part but in other situations there could be so many other client out there (different frontend services, different backend services etc.)

The drawback of this approach you may need to support several version of the same service which could be tricky but it is inevitable. Communication with clients would also be tricky in many situation.

On the other hand it gives you true power of microservice isolation and freedom.

Answer (score 0):

I think If you use docker in your DevOps env you can use docker-compose with `depends_on` property [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) [startup-order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) OR you should create a script bash (for example) that check the correct version of the frontend deployed before continue and included in your pipeline

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer.
I was talking about how to keep sync between repos when you deploy the depends_on only makes one app to run after the dependency but it doesn't verify the version.

Also the script yes, it's the way that most of the people are using so I was curious about new ways.

Thanks.